# Common style for different controls with the same custom properties

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, custom-controls

I have several custom controls that have in common some custom properties and I would like to apply a common style that triggers with those properties. I put those common properties in an interface (IMyControl) and made my controls implement it, but it seems that a style can't have an interface as TargetType...

My custom properties are two booleans: bMandatory and bIncomplete. The common style part is:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource FocusedBG}" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="bMandatory" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MandatoryBG}" />
    </Trigger>
    <MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="bMandatory" Value="True" />
            <Condition Property="bIncomplete" Value="True" />
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource IncompleteBG}" />
    </MultiTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

I also put in the interface the *IsKeyboardFocusWithin* bool and the *Background* brush and then tried with:

```
<Style x:Key="ControlRellenableEstilo">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="local:IMyControl.IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="local:IMyControl.Background" Value="{StaticResource FocusedBG}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="local:IMyControl.bMandatory" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="local:IMyControl.Background" Value="{StaticResource MandatoryBG}" />
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="local:IMyControl.bMandatory" Value="True" />
                <Condition Property="local:IMyControl.bIncomplete" Value="True" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource IncompleteBG}" />
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

It doesn't complain when building but, when the application is executed, it throws a XamlParseException that says

> Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.Setter.Value'

pointing at the line:
   `<Setter Property="local:IMyControl.Background" Value="{StaticResource FocusedBG}" />`

It has an inner exception with the following message:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: property'

The **Value="{StaticResource FocusedBG}"** part is working in the rest of my styles...
Any idea how could I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Setters operate on [dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) only, in an interface you cannot register them, and they can only be registered once, so even if you specify some field for them in the interface that probably is far from a good idea. You might want to consider using [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) or using a base-class with that property on it (which probably is not an option).

Comment: Using a base class is not an option because each custom control has its own base class, that is why I tried interfaces. Attached properties could do it with bMandatory and bIncomplete, but how would you handle the IsKeyboardFocusWithin?

Comment: @CarlosJ: Why don't you use the existing property in the from the framework? Why do you even have your own property like that?

Comment: I don´t have my own property, I put it in the interface so I could use it in the style because every control already had it, but it did not work.

Comment: @CarlosJ: What did you try? `UIElement.IsKeyBoardFocusWithin`?

Comment: I tried the second piece of xaml code that appears in my question. I have several controls (TextBox, DatePicker, ComboBox,...) with two custom boolean properties: bIncomplete and bMandatory. bIncomplete is set to *False* by default. If bMandatory is set to *True*, the control background brush should be MandatoryBG. When the user tries to send the info, a method checks if all the controls with bMandatory set to *True* have a correct value and, if any of them don't, set their bIncomplete properties to *True*. That should change their background brush to IncompleteBG.

Comment: Then I have been told to change the background brush to FocusedBG when one of my controls is focused. In order to do this, I tried to create an interface (IMyControl) with the four properties I need (bMandatory, bIncomplete, IsKeyboardFocusWithin and BackGround) and put the second piece of xaml code in my ResourceDictionary.

Comment: For the focus part, I have considered the [Focus Visual Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613567.aspx), but the bMandatory and bIncomplete problem is still there.

Comment: What i meant to ask was: What did you trigger on? i.e. this should work: `<Trigger Property="UIElement.IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">...</Trigger>`

Comment: All my controls are working with `<Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">` but right now they have that line within a style per control. What I want is to have only one style with those triggers, just one.
All of my controls have bIncomplete, bMandatory, IsKeyboardFocusWithin and Background, and they all must behave the same way with those properties. I am looking for a way to do this without code replication.

Comment: @CarlosJ: Use the code in my previous comment, if you have a universal style without `TargetType` you need the `UIElement.` in front of the property.

Comment: If I use that it does not compile because it sais that **Cannot resolve the Style Property 'Background'...**. If I try with `<Trigger Property="Control.IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True"><Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="{StaticResource Relleno}" /></Trigger>` then it sais the same with my custom properties **Cannot resolve the Style Property 'bMandatory'...**

Answer (score 0):

What about if you set a default value for 'local:IMyControl.Background' in the Style also, like:

```
<Style x:Key="ControlRellenableEstilo">

    <Setter Property="local:IMyControl.Background" Value="Gray" /> 
    <!--or use TemplateBinding to Parent to get suitable color-->

    <Style.Triggers>

        ... skipped ...

    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Also check a [Precedence List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing) on your CustomControl.

Comment: I've just tried and got the same exception. In [msdn: Styling and Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx) it is said *You can use a style on any element that derives from FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement.* so I guess an interface can't be a style TargetType. There must be some other way, but I am a bit lost. Thanks anyway.